# Extension activation failed, run the 'Developer: Toggle Developer Tools' command for more information

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Unable to run/debug run in my python file. I KNOW I downloaded python on my computer. I know I downloaded the extension in VS code. Every time I try to run even a simple print("abc") line of code I get nothing in the terminal and a message that reads

```
"Extension activation failed, run the 'Developer: Toggle Developer Tools' command for more information."
```

in addition to

```
"Python extension loading..."
```

and the extension never seems to finish loading its been hours.

How do I fix this I am working out of Windows

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Comment: Try installing a [pre-release version](https://imgur.com/1eu5FeW) of the extension.

Answer (score 4):

For example I have "Extension" named Python in the image below that gets updated or installed by vsCode automatically

1. You have to wait for the "Extensions" to be installed.
2. Make sure you have an internet connection.
3. make sure you have a fast internet connection so that it can be installed faster.
4. After installation restart "vsCode"

If it doesn't work for you, try uninstalling the extension and reinstalling it

This is all I know and it happened to me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the reason, for me I installed a pervious version for python EXTENSIONS, and issue fixed [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOD4s.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33554079)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the extensions and you'll find the extensions whose reload is required. Press reload and wait for the extension to refresh. Check the error message at the bottom to see if it still persists.

Comment: Hey Bob Kiongo, welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you to your answer! However, since it doesn't directly answers the posted question, but instead it requests more additional information, it would be much more appropriate to repost it as a comment to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem occurred when updating VS code to version 1.75.0 and python extension version was 2022.20.2, problem fixed when updating python extension to version 2023.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can install Extensions **Python Environment Manager**.

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall vscode (using software manager when on ubuntu). Solved it for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34451393)

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the extension Uncaught Errors you have this text:

Extension 'ms-toolsai.jupyter' CANNOT use API proposal: notebookCellExecutionState. Its package.json#enabledApiProposals-property declares: but NOT notebookCellExecutionState. The missing proposal MUST be added and you must start in extension development mode or use the following command line switch: --enable-proposed-api ms-toolsai.jupyter

So you have to call VSCode like this:
$ code . --enable-proposed-api ms-toolsai.jupyter